# Need help with a complex 3d scene (using Ogre and bullet)

Tags: 3d, mathematics, ogre, bullet-physics, simulations

In my setup there is a box with a hole on one side, and a freely movable "stick" (or bar, tube). This stick can be inserted/moved through the hole into the box. This hole is exactly as wide as the diameter of the stick.

In reality, when you would now hold the end of the stick in your hand and move the hand left/right or up/down, the other end of the stick, which is inside the box, would move into the opposite direction of your hand movement (because the stick is affixed at the pivot point where it is entering the box through the hole).

(I hope you understand what I mean so far.)

Now I need to simulate such a setup in a 3d program. I have already successfully developed an Ogre3d framework for this application, including bullet. But what I don't know is how I can implement in my program what I have described above. This application must include two more features:

1. The scene camera is attached to the end of the stick that is inserted into the box. So when the user would move the mouse (to control "his" end of the stick outside the box), then the camera attached to the stick would move in the opposite direction, as described above.
2. The stick has some length, and the user can push it further into the box, or pull it closer to him again. That means of course that the max. radius on which the end of the stick inside the box can move depends on how far the stick is pushed into the box. Thus, the more the stick is pushed into the box, the larger the max. radius of this end of the stick with the camera will be.

I understand this is maybe quite a complex thing, so I don't expect any real source code here. I already have the Ogre and bullet part as said up and running, as well as a camera attached to the stick. This works fine. What I don't know though is how I can simulate the setup described above. Especially the requirement that the stick is affixed at the position of the hole on the box, where it is inserted into the box.

Any ideas how I could approach to implement the described setup?

Comment: Wouldn't this be simple if you just rotate around the pivot point of the stick? Maybe you can draw a picture to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Byte56: Yes exactly, I am talking about this pivot point (sorry English is not my first language). But how can I rotate the stick around this pivot point? How can I tell Ogre/bullet to not move the whole stick, but the tip of it based on the tip's distance to this pivot point?

Comment: [how-can-i-rotate-about-an-arbitrary-point-in-3d-instead-of-the-origin](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/)

Comment: Can sombody please explain to me why this question has been down voted?

Comment: The down vote is likely because the question is a bit too localized, and it's nearly a duplicate. It currently has 4/5 votes to close as too localized. Did you not find the answer you needed in the question I linked?

Comment: @Byte56: Unfortunately not, but it seems that is my fault because I have not described what I am looking for well enough. I will need to think about what I really want, or rather how I can better explain it to the community, maybe with fewer words. Thanks for your reply though. Would you mind telling me what you mean with "too localized"?

Comment: Too localized means the question us unlikely to help any future visitors because it's too specific to you.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do, but it sounds like what you are looking for is [constraints](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Constraints)

Comment: @msell: Thank you very much, that looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered building a set of animations that go from rest post (stick with no interaction applied) to end poses (we need a picture to really get what you're talking about) and blending the animation(s) based on user input?

I may not understand the extent of your interactivity, or needs.